# MySQL optimize premature kill

Tags: mysql

I have an extremely large db table (around 30GB data file),  and I started optimizer on it with

```
mysqlcheck --optimize -A
```

Now, it's already taken more than 2 hours, and I'm not sure when it's going to finish.  Would it result in data loss if I prematurely kill the job,  because I want the table to be unlocked urgently?

Comment: asked 9 hours ago? Still looking for an answer?

Comment: Not really,  I killed the query and the data was intact :)  Thanks for asking anyway.  Should I close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove this from the "unanswered" list...

"Nope! It will NOT result in data loss if you prematurely kill the job, given your post facto confirmation that it did, indeed, not do so."

That said, when MySQL optimizes a table, it creates a new table in the process. The downside is that you sometimes cannot optimize a large table when you belatedly realize that it's consuming too much of the available hard disk space. The upside is that you can kill it prematurely without data loss.